# p4 resolved File status

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

As I understand, the files which have conflicts and are resolved manually , will be shown as "edit" when we invoke the p4 resolved command.

Format:-  - -** edit **from

However, for the same DB, for my colleague, its being shown as "merge" for the same file.

Note: The Data base versions which we have taken are of the same version. No discrepancies there.

Can you please let me know on the possible reasons for the same ?

Tried checking online for possible reasons, but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous because you don't say how you and your colleague are accessing the DB -- is it the same client file?  The same depot file open in two different clients?  If you're in two different clients, you are and your colleague are looking at two entirely different DB records.

Comment: @samwise, so basically, we are taking a release branch and integrating the changes from Mainline into Release Branch.  In this process, we both encounter a file, say, checker_sb.sv which has conflicts with respect to the same file in release branch. We edit the conflicts manually. Now , perforce must show checker_sb.sv as edited when we invoke p4 resolved. However, in my colleague's case, it shows the same file as merged, though he has resolved the conflicts manually as well.

Comment: Please note, we haven't checked in any file yet, we are speaking in terms of having the same file shown with different updates in our local DB.

Comment: I suspect you both did slightly different things to "manually" resolve the file.

Answer (score 1):

`p4 resolved` shows information for files opened in the current workspace only (remember that any number of workspaces can have the same depot file open for different pending actions), so if you and your colleague have the same file opened in two different workspaces, it is likely to be in two different states, unless you did everything *exactly* the same.  Changes are generally not synchronized between different workspaces until one of them `submit`s their local file and the other `sync`s it.

`edit from` doesn't necessarily mean a manual resolve.  A manual resolve might be also be recorded as `copy`, `merge`, or `ignore` if the result of the manual resolve is identical to the existing files matching those results (`copy` is the "theirs" file, `ignore` is "yours" i.e. the original workspace file, and `merged` is the auto-generated merge result).

Conversely, an automatic resolve can be "downgraded" to an `edit` in a variety of situations, such as:

- an additional resolve was performed against the file, such that the new file content no longer reflects the earlier automatic resolve
- the file's open action was changed (e.g. via `p4 edit`)

It is also possible to forcibly record a `merge from` for something that's actually an `edit from` at the time you resolve; I *think* you can only do this from the command line, and it looks like this:

```
c:\Perforce\test\merge\bar.txt - merging //stream/main/merge/foo.txt#4
Diff chunks: 0 yours + 0 theirs + 0 both + 1 conflicting
Accept(a) Edit(e) Diff(d) Merge (m) Skip(s) Help(?) e: e
Accept(a) Edit(e) Diff(d) Merge (m) Skip(s) Help(?) ae: am
Use 'ae' to indicate original edits: confirm accept merge (y/n)? y
//Samwise-dvcs-1509687817/merge/bar.txt - merge from //stream/main/merge/foo.txt
```

Note that the suggested option was `ae` (accept edit) but I overrode it with `am`; the CLI prompts to confirm that's what I wanted to do, but if I say yes, it'll go ahead and record it as a `merge`.

Separately from that, there are situations where different clients might show different output for the same resolve/integrate records, although I don't think that would be the case for `merged` vs `edit` -- you'd more typically see this in a case where a very old client renders a newer record type like `moved from` or `undid` as `add` or `ignore` for backward compatibility purposes.

Comment: thanks for the reply. You mentioned-" edit from doesn't necessarily mean a manual resolve". In our case, we are editing the file, i.e. resolving the conflicts occurring between our file and the main line version. So post this resolution, under p4 resolved, the file must be shown as "edit" right? Say its not matching anything (i.e. local file or the main line file) .

Comment: Not necessarily.  One more possibility (I'll edit the answer to include this) is that even after you edit a file, you can actually force a `merge` record to be created (you might do this if the edit you made is something that shouldn't be reverse-integrated to the source).

Comment: thanks samwise for the answer. Will check it out.